# How many permutations are there in which only the odd integers are deranged?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $a_n := \lvert\{\pi \in S_n : \text{$\pi(i) \neq i$ for all odd $i$}\}\rvert$ denote the number of bijections $\pi\colon [n] \rightarrow [n]$ with no odd fixed points.

So how many permutations are there in which only the odd integers are deranged? It seems to me that I only have to consider the cases where $n$ is odd, that is, $n = 2m +1$.

Then by Inclusion Exclusion I gives:

$a_n = n! \sum_{r=0}^{m} (-1)^k {m \choose k}(2m + 1 -k)! $

However, it doesn't feel right since I also think I have to consider the even $n$ case.

And after that the textbook wants me to prove the following: $\frac{a_n}{n!}$ goes to $\frac{1}{e^{1/2}}$ when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is a better fit for https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Aah I see; is there an option that the question can be migrated?

Comment: The same question was asked less than a week ago and I think was migrated, so you might as well look for an existing question before requesting that this one be migrated.

Comment: There's a difference between "no odd fixed points" and "only the odd integers are deranged". Better figure out which one you want, before you go asking questions about it.

Comment: This appears to be a question about homework.  ("And after that the textbook wants me to prove the following...")  @Combideal:  This is not a site for homework help, but rather for research-level math questions.  I'm not sure your professor really wants you getting the answers to your homework on math.stackexchange.com either, but I'll leave that between you and your professor.